# COM_DESCRIPTOR in PE-files

Tags: portable-executable

I'm looking for the information about COM_DESCRIPTOR directory in PE files. What is it and what is it used for? I've read the structure of PE-files and still don't understand what is COM_DESCRIPTOR.

Thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922).

Answer (score 2):

"COM Descriptor Directory" in PE Header is also known as "CLR Header". It is only present in Managed PE Images (created with C# and other Dot Net compilers). You can dump content of this directory with DumpBin /CLRHRADER option. For example:

> DumBin /CLRHEADER someapp.exe

clr Header:

```
          48 cb
        2.05 runtime version
        30C4 [    1DEC] RVA [size] of MetaData Directory
           1 flags
               IL Only
     6000004 entry point token
        4EB0 [    2560] RVA [size] of Resources Directory
           0 [       0] RVA [size] of StrongNameSignature Directory
           0 [       0] RVA [size] of CodeManagerTable Directory
           0 [       0] RVA [size] of VTableFixups Directory
           0 [       0] RVA [size] of ExportAddressTableJumps Directory
           0 [       0] RVA [size] of ManagedNativeHeader Directory
```

RVA in this directory entry points to IMAGE_COR20_HEADER defined in WinNt.h. It is also defined in CorHdr.h :

```
typedef struct IMAGE_COR20_HEADER
{
    // Header versioning
    DWORD                   cb;              
    WORD                    MajorRuntimeVersion;
    WORD                    MinorRuntimeVersion;

    // Symbol table and startup information
    IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY    MetaData;        
    DWORD                   Flags;           

    // The main program if it is an EXE (not used if a DLL?)
    // If COMIMAGE_FLAGS_NATIVE_ENTRYPOINT is not set, EntryPointToken represents a managed entrypoint.
    // If COMIMAGE_FLAGS_NATIVE_ENTRYPOINT is set, EntryPointRVA represents an RVA to a native entrypoint
    // (depricated for DLLs, use modules constructors intead). 
    union {
        DWORD               EntryPointToken;
        DWORD               EntryPointRVA;
    };

    // This is the blob of managed resources. Fetched using code:AssemblyNative.GetResource and
    // code:PEFile.GetResource and accessible from managed code from
    // System.Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream.  The meta data has a table that maps names to offsets into
    // this blob, so logically the blob is a set of resources. 
    IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY    Resources;
    // IL assemblies can be signed with a public-private key to validate who created it.  The signature goes
    // here if this feature is used. 
    IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY    StrongNameSignature;

    IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY    CodeManagerTable;           // Depricated, not used 
    // Used for manged codee that has unmaanaged code inside it (or exports methods as unmanaged entry points)
    IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY    VTableFixups;
    IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY    ExportAddressTableJumps;

    // null for ordinary IL images.  NGEN images it points at a code:CORCOMPILE_HEADER structure
    IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY    ManagedNativeHeader;

} IMAGE_COR20_HEADER, *PIMAGE_COR20_HEADER;
```

Comment: According to MS PE Header specification, this section is not documented. See the link below for details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/pe-format#the-cormeta-section-object-only. Most fields are explained in the IMAGE_COR20_HEADER type declaration, which I have copied in my original post.